# Sending uitextview data to container view

Tags: uibutton, uilabel, uitextview, swift4, uicontainerview

I have a view controller with a container view embedded that contains a uibutton and a uilabel. In the view controller, I have a uitextview with it's character range limited to 150.

What I am trying to do is get the uibutton located in the container view to change it's state when text is entered in the uitextview and also get the uilabel (character counter) to decrease as text is entered.

I'm just looking for a shove in the right direction. I would like to post an image for clarity, but sadly I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your VC which have your container and textField with UITextViewDelegate. After that you will you use "textViewDidEndEditing" method to do your jobs. For example:

```
extension myVC: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
         myButton.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

If you have more than one textView and do sth different, you need to set tag to textView's.

```
myTextView.tag = 1

extension myVC: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
         if textView.tag == 1 {
              myButton.isHidden = true
         }
    }
}
```

I hope I understood very well your question and help you.

Comment: Not sure I understand. But the UIbutton and uilabel are located inside the containerview which is a separate class. Extending the parent VC still wouldn't allow me to access the button or label.